# Chrome extension: On change input in default_popup is not working correctly?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

mainifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Search",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Search",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "search.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": ["jquery-3.1.1.min.js", "content.js"]
    }]
}
```

popup.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="domain">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="content.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

content.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#domain").change(function() {
        console.log($("#domain").val());
    });
});
```

The event `change` input when I typed is not working correctly. For example:

When I type the word `test`, in the console only show the word `test`. It should be: `t`, `te`, `tes`, `test`.

Or when I used `alert` instead of `console.log` is not working too, but when I clicked in the `popup.html` the alert displayed and disappear quickly

Comment: The [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) is working correctly. The behavior you describe is what you get with the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input).

Comment: @Makyen Thank you, I changed to `on input` and it's working correctly